# Securely deleting files, while attempting to protect the user against obviously dangerous inputs

Tags: ruby

As far as I can tell, no gem currently exists to wrap shred, the *nix utility to securely delete files.  I created a small class to do this, the key methods are:

```
def self.run cmd
  stdout,stderr,status = Open3.capture3 cmd
  raise "Failed executing #{cmd}: stdout: #{stdout}, stderr: #{stderr}, status #{status}" unless status.nil? || status == 0
  stdout
end

def self.validate_path path, required_regex=nil
  raise if required_regex && !required_regex.is_a?(Regexp)
  File.expand_path(path).tap do |path|
    raise if path == '/'
    raise if required_regex && !path.match(required_regex)
  end
end

def self.dir! path, opts={}
  return unless Dir.exist?(path)
  validate_path path, opts[:path_must_match]

  stdout = run "find #{path} -type f -exec #{shred_cmd} '{}' ';'"
  FileUtils.rm_rf path
  stdout
end
```

- find is used to execute shred, since it lacks a recursive option.  I initially tried execdir instead of exec for security, but travis and other build environments hate it.  Potential problem?
- validate_path tries to keep the user from screwing themselves by expanding the path, better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- `def self.run cmd`: Omiting parentheses on signatures is less and less idiomatic as time goes by, people have realized they are harder to read. I'd put them.
- `Open3.capture3 cmd`: It's also less idiomatic than it was years ago to omit parentheses on calls (except for very specific DSL code).
- `stdout,stderr,status`: Always a space after a comma.
- `def self.validate_path path, required_regex=nil`. Positional optional arguments tend to get messy when you need to add new ones. I'd use always an `options = {}` hash. Ruby 2.0 has keyword arguments so this problem is fortunately gone.
- `raise if required_regex && !required_regex.is_a?(Regexp)`. I wouldn't check the type of the variable, it's the caller's responsability to get it right.
- `File.expand_path(path).tap`. This kind of `tap` usages are IMO cryptic and unnecessary.
- Lots of `raise ... if condition`: Inline conditionals save some lines at the cost of making the branching logic harder to follow. I prefer writing full-fledged indentend conditionals (indentation is a powerful conveyor of information).
- `Open3.capture3 cmd`. Running command from strings is dangerous (files with spaces anyone?), you should use some mechanism to escape them.
- `find #{path} -type f`. It's ok to call external commands when the the language is unable to do the task, but here you can easily perform a recursive find with, well, module [find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html).

I'd write something like this:

```
require 'find'
require 'open3'
require 'fileutils'
require 'shellwords'

class SafeRemover
  def self.run(command_array)
    command_string = Shellwords.join(command_array)
    stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command_string)
    if !status || status == 0
      stdout
    else
      fail("Failed executing #{cmd}: stdout: #{stdout}, stderr: #{stderr}, status #{status}")
    end
  end

  def self.validate_path(path, options = {})
    required_regexp = options[:required_regexp]        
    path2 = File.expand_path(path)
    if !Dir.exist?(path2)
      fail("Directory does not exist: #{path2}")
    elsif path2 == "/"
      fail("You cannot delete /")
    elsif required_regexp && !path2.match(required_regexp)
      fail("Path and required_regexp do not match")
    end
  end

  def self.dir!(root_directory, options = {})
    validate_path(root_directory, :required_regexp => options[:path_must_match])
    paths = Find.find(root_directory).select { |p| FileTest.file?(p) }
    output = paths.each_slice(100).map { |paths| run(["shred", *paths]) }.join
    FileUtils.rm_rf(root_directory)
    output
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @tokland.  I think we differ on style issues (the less parens the better!), but I understand your points about more explicit branching.  Your approach of invoking shred independently is interesting, and I like that it bypasses whatever issues find might have.  I wonder about performance though, since you are creating a new subshell for every file deleted.  I suppose bench-marking the two approaches would be the way to tell.

Comment: @juwiley: Note the `each_slice(100)`, I am spawning 1 shred per 100 files. Anyway, in your code, won't a find -exec fork 1 shred per file? Regarding the parens: yes, it's subjective. But IMHO Haskell/Ocaml got it right in the parens-less section, you can either have parens or commas to separate arguments, but commas and optional parens (Ruby/Coffescript) is usally a mess.

Comment: Also the Shellwords module is a good find, hadn't been aware of it.

Comment: Duh, you're exactly right about -exec.  I think using xargs would get around that, but it may croak on a certain number of files which brings us back to your approach and makes sense.

Comment: `xargs`, yes, instead of find -exec I tend to do something like: `find directory | xargs -n100 command`.